# Directly loading .RData from github

Tags: r, url, github, load

I want to load `PakPMICS2018bh.RData` data from https://github.com/myaseen208/PakPMICS2018Data/ and used the following code which throws the error:

```
library(RCurl)
PakPMICS2018bhURL <- "https://github.com/myaseen208/PakPMICS2018Data/raw/master/PakPMICS2018bh.RData"
load(url(PakPMICS2018bhURL))
```

> Error in load(url(PakPMICS2018bhURL)) : 
>         the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection

I am wondering what is wrong with my code. Any help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in your code, it should work fine.
This, for example, loads an Rdata file from github normally

```
load(url("https://github.com/mawp/spict/raw/master/spict/data/pol.rda"))
```

Your problem comes from the files you are trying to open, they are saved with the serialization format 3 that was introduced in R version 3.5, using `save(version = 3)`

> R has new serialization format (version 3) which supports custom serialization of ALTREP framework objects. These objects can still be serialized in format 2, but less efficiently. Serialization format 3 also records the current native encoding of unflagged strings and converts them when de-serialized in R running under different native encoding. Format 3 comes with new serialization magic numbers (RDA3, RDB3, RDX3). Format 3 can be selected by version = 3 in save(), serialize() and saveRDS(), but format 2 remains the default for all serialization and saving of the workspace. **Serialized data in format 3 cannot be read by versions of R prior to version 3.5.0.**

**EDIT**

After some more research I think it is a bug (or a feature ?). 
For files saved with `compression` argument equal to `FALSE`, `TRUE` or `gz` the code works as expected in R version >= 3.5. But for compression equal to `xz` which seems to be your case it does not work.

There are two options: either save the files with gz compression, or use the workaround from @user113156's answer.

Comment: Thanks @alko989 for your answer. I'm using `R version 3.6.0`, so what is your take in this case? What should I do?

Comment: I was just testing it (was a bit of a struggle to update R to 3.5 in ubuntu) and it seems that the load function does not work with the new serialization format. Probably a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Just make sure you set your working directory.

```
setwd("SET YOUR Working Directory - the file will download here")
working_directory <- getwd()
if (!file.exists("PakPMICS2018bh.RData")) {
  download.file(   "https://github.com/myaseen208/PakPMICS2018Data/raw/master/PakPMICS2018bh.RData",   "PakPMICS2018bhURL.RData")

  load(file.path(working_directory, "PakPMICS2018bhURL.RData"))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @user113156 for your answer. What is wrong with my code? Actually I just want to load the data without downloading it. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the technical distinction. How would it work to load the data without downloading it? Is the goal to download to a temporary file, or to make sure the source file gets deleted after the load?

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK to `read` rather than `load` the file, this works for me:

```
readRDS(url("https://.../FILENAME.rda"))
```